# Access Python Spyder in Browser like Rstudio or Jupyter notebook (NOT SSH)

Tags: python, anaconda, spyder

We have a Linux server with Jupyterhub installed and can be accessed by users over browser, similarly we are able to access Rstudio. 
Is it possible to install Spyder on the Linux server and provide access via web browser. Multiple users will be accessing it simultaneously.  We are not looking for remote desktop or SSH solution. 
Thanks

Comment: What about pycharm?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

(*Spyder maintainer here*) Spyder can't work inside a web browser because it's a pure desktop application, sorry.

Comment: Thanks for the info Carlos! I have python installed on a linux server and I can access it through putty, however when I try to use spyder's (3.5) "connect to existing kernel" by providing necessary details, it just throws up error message box, sometime it just stops responding.  I am using putty's .ppk file (converted to .pem) for ssh authentication and a kernel-xx.json for kernel info.  Any thoughts on this. Couldn't find any solution on net for this. Thanks

Comment: If you're trying to connect from Windows to Linux, you need to install the `paramiko` package on the same environment you have Spyder installed on Windows. Then you could use our *Connect to existing kernel* feature. If things are still not working after that, please open an issue in our [issues tracker](https://github.com/spyder-ide/spyder/issues) to continue the discussion there.

Comment: Is this still a limitation in Spyder 5. I'm asking because I see that I can try Spyder 5 on the web via a Binder notebook. So I wonder if there is a way to make it run on a web now.

Comment: I think you saw a VNC desktop there, @hnagaty, so the IDE is run inside a virtual machine and you receive screencast of a GUI-based app with no client-side component, rather than using a true browser-based (client-server) app like Jupyter Notebook or VS Code Server.

Answer (score 2):

How about broadening your search space to include [VS Code Server](https://github.com/coder/code-server) as an alternative? It closely resembles the classic Windows (GUI) version, but it has client-server architecture, so your code resides and runs on the server, but the user interface is rendered locally in the browser, so no graphical desktop needs to be installed on the server.